# How to copy four textbox values to a textarea in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which contains four `textboxes` and one `textarea` field.

The form something like request form. I want the `content` of four `textboxes` get copied to `textarea`.

For this I have write `onkeyup` event which simultaneously copy its value to textarea but I want all the four textbox values get copied to the text area.

This is the code I wrote for `onkeyup` event

```
<input type="text" id="C.name" name="C.name" required onkeyup="document.getElementById('message').value=this.value">
```

And also I am attaching a picture of my form for the better idea, here in the picture you could see the value of[image] one textbox get copied to textarea.

What should I do so that the value of all textbox get copied to textarea

Comment: It would have been easier for us to help you if you actually supplied us with a live example within jsfiddle to see what's actually going wrong in your implementation..
We're glad to help but next time please supply us with some of your own preperation so we'd not be stuck with the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function, and call it from the `onkeyup` attribute. Your function might look like:

```
function fillMessage() {
    var nam = document.getElementById('name');
    var com = document.getElementById('company');
    var ema = document.getElementById('email');
    var pho = document.getElementById('phone');
    var msg = document.getElementById('message');
    msg.value = nam.value + com.value + ema.value + pho.value;
}
```

And each form field would have the attribute `onkeyup="fillMessage()"`. Here is a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qmrt7z0w/).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to concat the input values and bind the key-up event to all inputs, something along the lines of this example:

```
var aggregateInput = function()
{
    var value = jQuery('input[name="name"]').val() + 
        jQuery('input[name="company"]').val() + 
        jQuery('input[name="email"]').val() + 
        jQuery('input[name="number"]').val();

    jQuery('textarea[name="aggregated"]').val(value);
}

jQuery('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', aggregateInput);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9fe2532/1/

**Update:**

As you never indicated you're using jQuery within your project I've created a non-jQuery version as well. Bind the following function using the onkeyup input attribute on all your inputs using onkeyup="aggregateInput()":

```
function aggregateInput()
{
    var value = document.getElementById('nameInput').value
        + document.getElementById('companyInput').value
        + document.getElementById('emailInput').value
        + document.getElementById('numberInput').value;

    document.getElementById('aggregated').value = value;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v9fe2532/4/

Comment: slick jQuery solution. i like how you applied the `onkeyup` to all inputs all in one place.
your non-jQuery solution seems needlessly complicated. why loop through all input tags when you can grab the four you want by id?

Comment: I'm not a huge fan using too much needless ID attributes within my elements, probably because it's such a heavy CSS selector. You are right when it comes down to simplicity within the scripts, I've updated my fiddle and example accordingly.